# transient analysis with square wave

Tags: transient

I was doing the transient analysis experiment with the Series LCR circuit, and my mentor asked me some questions, which I don't have a clue about. I read but did not get any rigorous satisfactory answer.

the very basic question was, (1) Why we use square wave instead of the sinusoidal wave to study the transient response?

why can't we perform this study using a sinusoidal wave? (I was using CRO)

Comment: The basic methods are time domain step or square wave lower than the resonant f or swept frequency response for half power bandwidth (BWj  or -3dB fo/BW=Q on the current

Comment: Fundamentally, it comes down to the fact that a transient (and the edge of a square wave) contain all frequencies while a sinewave contains only one. Learn the relationship between a transient (delta function) and a step function (single edge of a square wave)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in studying a transient response, what you need to do is apply a stimulus and observe the system (your LCR circuit) as it evolves to its steady state. When doing this theoretically, the two most suitable stimuli are the Dirac's delta function/pulse and the step function, because both apply some forcing quantity in zero time and let you calculate how the system evolves immediately after such stimulus has reached its own steady state (back to zero for the pulse, some positive value for the step). Those are called pulse and step responses, respectively.

Instead, when doing this experimentally, the easiest thing to do is apply a step (the steeper, the better), just because good pulses are somewhat harder to generate. With a common laboratory setup, the best thing you could do is to apply a square wave (which, after all, can be interpreted as a sequence of steps of opposite polarities) and observe the periodic result on an oscilloscope, so that you can see your LCR circuit response at every edge of your square wave. Of course, you need to take care that the period of the applied square wave is long enough to let the system reach its steady state before receiving an opposite stimulus.

Now, back at the core of your question, from the above you can see why a sinusoidal wave is not suitable for such a study: <s>Since a sinusoidal wave is constantly changing, it does not allow the system to reach its steady state</s>; it continuously forces the system to change as it tries to keep up with the sinusoid. Still what you would observe and how well your LCR circuit follows the stimulus depends on the frequency of your input sinusoid.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments regarding the above strickenout sentence, a couple of remarks are required.

- The term "steady-state" that I used is not correct because it indicates an equilibrium condition when the system continuously evolves forced by the input but transients have already vanished. This can be done with sinusoids (even though there exists a steady state to a square-wave input too); indeed, frequency-domain characterisation methods like Bode diagrams apply input sinusoids and measure the output amplitude and phase (relative to the input) at various frequencies.
- However, the point of your question is to see and measure the transient behaviour of your system. This is usually done with a square wave input because it provides a periodic step input which allows you to observe a "piece-wise transient" (in the words of Vicente Cunha) output where, if the square wave frequency is low enough for your system, the responses to single edges have enough time to settle and transients have enough time to vanish. As mentioned in the comments, this kind of "piece-wise analysis" cannot be done with sinusoids.

Comment: 'Since a sinusoidal wave is constantly changing, it does not allow the system to reach its steady state' - I understand your message but this is not 100% correct. If this were true, Bode diagrams would be useless, since they present a gain and phase response to sinusoids at steady-state. Note that a constant input is equivalent to a sinusoid of frequency 0.

Comment: @VicenteCunha I see your point, and I apologise for putting it in the wrong English terms. I meant that the issue with a sinusoid is that it doesn't allow the system to "finally settle to an equilibrium point after the transient has vanished". I'll be glad to edit the answer with the correct terminology for this, should anyone provide it.

Comment: Maybe the best way to phrase it is that an output to square waves can be seen as "piece-wise transients". In the context of waveforms, there would also be a steady-state to a square wave with fixed period, but when you focus the analysis on just a "step occurence" of the waveform (that's what I mean by "piece-wise") then you can study the transient response of the system. The same piece-wise analysis cannot be done with sinusoids.

Comment: LCR have perfectly observable characteristics even with sines. It's only a frequency domain analysis instead of a time domain analysis. There's some horrible convolution theorem that also guarantees that you can switch between one and the other. An LRC in time domain is more intuitive to observe. Also the step or the pulse are the basic stimuli for system analysis. Remember that a capacitor is both a dv/dt impedance and a charge container, the dualism is the same